# Why won't libreoffice install?

Tags: debian, libreoffice

```
Err:1 http://security-cdn.debian.org buster/updates/main armhf libreoffice-style-tango all 1:6.1.5-3+deb10u2
  404  Not Found [IP: ]
Err:2 http://security-cdn.debian.org buster/updates/main armhf uno-libs3 armhf 6.1.5-3+deb10u2
  404  Not Found [IP: ]
Err:3 http://security-cdn.debian.org buster/updates/main armhf ure armhf 6.1.5-3+deb10u2
  404  Not Found [IP: 
Err:4 http://security-cdn.debian.org buster/updates/main armhf libreoffice-core armhf 1:6.1.5-3+deb10u2
 E: Failed to fetch http://security-cdn.debian.org/pool/updates/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-base_6.1.5-3+deb10u2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: ]
E: Failed to fetch http://security-cdn.debian.org/pool/updates/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-calc_6.1.5-3+deb10u2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: ]
E: Failed to fetch http://security-cdn.debian.org/pool/updates/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-draw_6.1.5-3+deb10u2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.112.204 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security-cdn.debian.org/pool/updates/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-impress_6.1.5-3+deb10u2_armhf.deb  404  No
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Your system isn't resolving the addresses of the repositories. Does it have a network connection? Can you install anything with `apt`?

Comment: Did you `apt-get update` as the message recommends?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current version is [`1:6.1.5-3+deb10u3`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libreoffice) and `1:6.1.5-3+deb10u2` no longer exists. It seems your package index is outdated.

Try again with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Comment: Actually, that's what it says to do in the error message which the OP did not read properly: "... run apt-get update ..."